# Timeline with load more function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have created a CSS and HTML timeline section, but because i am so newbie to create js for this, so i asking you to help me to create load more button, which start to show 3 div then when every time click the button show 3, this is my main question. so i will show you my html which i created, hope you understand my request.

```
<!--Timeline Section Start-->
<section class='timeline pt-100 pb-100' data-scroll-index='2'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col'>
        <div class='section-title'>
          <div class='main-title'>
            <h4>My <span>Experience</span></h4>
            <h6>My Recent Experiences</h6>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='main-timeline'>
        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2016 - Mar 2017</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2016 - Mar 2017</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2016 - Mar 2017</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2016 - Mar 2017</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2016 - Mar 2017</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class='timeline'>
          <div class='timeline-icon'/>
          <div class='timeline-content'>
            <span class='date'>Apr 2017 - Present</span>
            <h5 class='title'>Any Title here</h5>
            <p class='description'>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum mattis felis vitae risus pulvinar tincidunt. Nam ac venenatis enim. Aenean hendrerit justo sed.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Timeline Section End-->
```

Answer (score 1):

first, your timeline tag inside main-timeline div don't have a closing tag. Put a closing tag in order for the below script to work.

paste this Jquery cdn in your header

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

second, hide first all your div which has a timeline class inside of your main timeline class, so

```
<style type="text/css">
      .main-timeline > .timeline {
        display: none;
      }
</style>
```

last is paste this script to your body tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var display_timeline = 3
        $('.main-timeline > .timeline').eq(display_timeline).css('display', 'block'); // show the first 3 timeline tag.

        $('#load-btn').click(function() { // add one timeline tag every click of load button, you can change it to 3
            display_timeline =  display_timeline + 1
            $('.main-timeline > .timeline').eq(display_timeline).css('display', 'block'); 
        });
 });
```

note: display_timeline variable must not greater to your timeline div length. Load more button will not show those elements if it is greater than.

Comment: where i could put the btn html , would you mind to show me full example ? or please would you mind to show live demo for on jsfiddle. please be patient with me,

Comment: please check this
https://jsfiddle.net/adonisalbelda/27ztorx9/